# Code that no longer works after last pandas update

Tags: python, pandas

My code used to work, now it does not since the last version of PANDAS

```
iterator = ['18', '19', '20', '21']
for i in iterator:
    locals()["List1_20" + i] = List1[List1['service_date'].str.contains("20{}-".format(i)]
    locals()["List2_20" + i] = locals()["List1_20" + i][
        locals()["List1_20" + i]['is_provider_server'] == 'YES']\
            .groupby(['provider_number'])['is_provider_server'].count().reset_index().rename(columns={'is_provider_server': "provider_server"})
```

I get this error

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: I don't see an error message, and it would help if you could properly format your code as a code block.

Comment: Sorry I edited it

Comment: Try using `.str.contains` instead of `.contains`.

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: Then it sounds like you're searching for strings in pandas Series that do not have strings stored in it.

Comment: Could you provide content of `List1`? It's hard to tell when you haven't provided MWE (it seems `service_data` column is not of string type, but probably of datetime thus having `dt` accessor instead of `str`).

Comment: @Nerxis Yes it is datetime data, thats is why I need to do .str first, it used to work now not

Comment: @RaulA.OcasioGonzalez: You cannot use `.str` on datetime data, check my answer, if that solves your issues.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: It's hard to tell when you haven't provided any data for your question and you haven't provided your pandas versions (before the update and after it). If you want better answer, please, provide data and pandas versions.*

First of all, you should find out how pandas accessors methods works, check e.g. [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-dtype-specific-operations-accessors-c749bafb30a4).

From the error and your comments in the discussion, `List1['service_date']` is not a string object, but a datetime object. Such object does not have any `.str` method and therefore pandas will throw an error (you can use `.str` accessor only with string values). You have mainly two options how to solve it:

**1. Convert datetime to string**

You can do it e.g. with `astype` method or with `strftime` method. I would reccommend the latter because you can define date format you want. Then the line where you use `contains` check could look like:

```
# if using astype
List1[List1['service_date'].astype(str).str.contains("20{}-".format(i))]

# if using strftime (you have to provide datetime format you are interested in)
List1[List1['service_date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").str.contains("20{}-".format(i))]
```

**2. Use `.dt` attributes for datetime checks**

It seems you are looking for rows that contains given year in "service_date" column. In such case it's much better to use check against year attribute instead of using contains method on string values. You could do the following:

```
List1[List1['service_date'].dt.year.isin([int("20{}-".format(i))]]
```

It's a bit shorter, but the main advantage is that it's much clearer what you are doing and you do not have to do any unnecessary conversion from datetime to strings.